# Microsoft Access 2013 - Windows 10 - PopUp Window disappears

Tags: ms-access

we are using Microsfot Access  2013 on Windows 10 system and when we open the application to run a query which outputs data to a table, the button which creates the popup form / window to enter the date range somehow just disappears.

Other systems using the same tool do not have this problem, and the tool was working just fine yesterday.

Any one have an ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the database was used on a multi-monitor setup it's possible the forms position has been stored "off screen".

Open the pop up in design view (It *should* appear!), and set AutoCentre property to true, and resave the pop up. It then should always appear in the middle of the current screen.